# Confused about the meaning of Unix vs. BSD flags format for the "ps" command

Tags: linux, ps

I have read that the `ps` command can take flags in two format:

- The Unix format in which you should precede the flags
  with a dash.
- The BSD format in which you should not precede the flags with a
  dash.

Now does the same flags can be used with both formats, for example do the following commands mean the same things:

```
ps -x
ps x
```

Or does the Unix format has its own set of flags, while the BSD format has an entirely different set of flags?

Comment: It's funny that the only manual that mentions the dash-less "BSD options" is a Linux manual. None of the BSD manuals mentions them (but they are supported).

Comment: That is intriguing... Perhaps they used to be mentioned, some archeology would no doubt shed light on the matter.

Comment: @StephenKitt They seem to have been removed in favour of the "dashed" options in BSD 4.4, i.e. before 1993 when NetBSD initially imported the source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) answers your question:

> Options of different types may be freely mixed, but conflicts can appear. There are some synonymous options, which are functionally identical, due to the many standards and `ps` implementations that this `ps` is compatible with.
>
> Note that `ps -aux` is distinct from `ps aux`. The POSIX and UNIX standards require that `ps -aux` print all processes owned by a user named "x", as well as printing all processes that would be selected by the `-a` option. If the user named "x" does not exist, this ps may interpret the command as `ps aux` instead and print a warning. This behavior is intended to aid in transitioning old scripts and habits. It is fragile, subject to change, and thus should not be relied upon.

The flags are different, but can be combined. Typically you’d pick one though, *e.g.* either `ps aux` or `ps -ef` to see details of all processes, not a mixture.

The only `x` flag is the BSD one, so `ps x` and `ps -x` produce the same result; but that doesn’t work for flags defined in both variants.

All this is specific to [`procps` and `procps-ng`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/ps/HACKING). The equivalence of `ps x` and `ps -x` is the result of a “second chance” parsing stage which is invoked if a first pass doesn’t fully parse all the arguments; this isn’t documented in the manpage but is mentioned in [the `HACKING` file in the source code](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/ps/HACKING):

> Unless the personality forces BSD parsing, parser.c tries to parse the
> command line as a mixed BSD+SysV+Gnu mess. On failure, BSD parsing is
> attempted. If BSD parsing fails *after* SysV parsing has been attempted,
> the error message comes from the original SysV parse.

Comment: I wonder what they mean by "The POSIX and UNIX standards"?

Comment: @Kusalananda presumably [POSIX `ps`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) and SUS...

Comment: @Kusalananda: Originally, POSIX was a set of standards developed by the IEEE, and international standards body. UNIX is a trademark that has gone through a lot of hands, and currently resides with the Open Group; there used to be set of standards associated with whether or not your are allowed to use the trademark. The Open Group is an industry consortium. They had different philosophies: POSIX was prescriptive (it specified what a POSIX system *must be*), UNIX was descriptive (it described what common Unix systems *are*). POSIX developed new APIs (e.g. POSIX threads, POSIX ACLs), UNIX …

Comment: … only described *already existing* usage. In the late 90s, the different groups formed The Austin Group, to develop a *single* specification that is identically published by the IEC, the IEEE, ISO, and The Open Group as POSIX and The Single Unix Specification (SUS) (although the Open Group's SUS is larger than the others and includes parts not covered by POSIX). SUS is conservative, in that it tries to only describe already existing widely-used, battle-tested APIs. The only exception is the `pax` Portable Archive Utility and Portable Archive Format, which was developed, because they couldn't

Comment: figure out how to unify `tar` and `cpio`, and so they decided to develop a completely new spec instead, a utility called `pax` that is mainly based on the (more POSIXy) `cpio` command (as opposed to the arcane options format of `tar`) and an archive format that is based on POSIX `tar`, with support for pretty much every feature you'd want (ACLs, XATTRs, very long filenames, sparse files, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. "The only x flag is the BSD one, so ps x and ps -x produce the same result". Does the manpage of ps say that if a dashless flag  in BSD not explicitly mentioned to have a dash equivalent in POSIX will implicitly have a dash equivalent in POSIX?

Comment: @Tim the manpage doesn’t mention it. It’s the result of `procps`’s “second chance” parsing: if a first parser pass, treating everything “by the book”, doesn’t handle all the arguments, a second pass is run in BSD mode.

Comment: Is -x parsed as x in the first pass or second?

Comment: @Tim I think you can figure that out yourself; take a wild guess.