# Which flags of the "ps" command are for the Unix flags format and which flags are for the BSD flags format?

Tags: linux, ps

The `ps` command can take flags in two format:

- The Unix format in which you should precede the flags with a dash.
- The BSD format in which you should not precede the flags with a dash.

I skimmed through the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) for the `ps` command to see which flags are for the Unix flags format and which flags are for the BSD flags format, but I did not find anything.

---

***Edit:*** this is not a duplicate, in the other question I am asking if the flags are different for Unix and BSD flags format, while in this question I am asking what are the flags for the Unix flags format and what are the flags for the BSD flags format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about the meaning of Unix vs. BSD flags format for the "ps" command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359323/confused-about-the-meaning-of-unix-vs-bsd-flags-format-for-the-ps-command)

Comment: The manpage in your own link shows quite clearly which options begin with a dash and which do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) doesn’t group options by style, it groups them by function. You can distinguish the style by looking at how the options are presented:

- BSD options are listed with no leading dash (`a`, `g`, `T`, `r`, `x`...);
- POSIX options are listed with a single leading dash (`-A`, `-a`, `-d`, `-e`, `-N`...);
- GNU long options are listed with two leading dashes (`--deselect`...).

As Kusalananda suggests, it’s a good idea to just use POSIX options and only refer to the other options when you need to understand someone else’s use of `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX standard [describes the `ps` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/ps.html) with the following synopsis:

```
ps [-aA] [-defl] [-g grouplist] [-G grouplist]
   [-n namelist] [-o format]... [-p proclist] [-t termlist]
   [-u userlist] [-U userlist]
```

Since there obviously is some confusion around the "UNIX options" and the "BSD options" for `ps`, and since none of OpenBSD, NetBSD, FreeBSD and macOS even lists the "BSD options" (dash-less flags) in their manuals for `ps`, maybe it's better to forget about them and see them as part of a closed chapter in UNIX's history?

The POSIX Rationale section for `ps` does say that there are incompatibilities between System V-based Unices and BSD-based Unices with regards to the implementation of `ps` (and the reasoning behind standardising the flags the way that was done), but it never mentions dash-less flags.

For reference:

- [OpenBSD `ps(1)` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/ps)
- [NetBSD `ps(1)` manual](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ps++NetBSD-current)
- [FreeBSD `ps(1)` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)
- [macOS `ps(1)` manual](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

PS support three (3) types of usage syntax styles:

- UNIX style, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash - e.g. `ps -aux`
- BSD style, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash - e.g. `ps aux`
- GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes e.g. `ps --aux`